# .htaccess way to serve index.html/index.php based on timestamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching

Let's say I've got a simple script (`index.php`) which pulls in a remote page, collects data from it, does some formatting and saves a new page. This new page (`index.html`) is then served to the client based on a usual cache/timestamp control.

So, in essence, what it might look like simplified:

```
<?
if ( filemtime('index.html')+3600 > strtotime('now') ) {
    // collect_remote_stuff();
    // save_new_index_html();
} else {
    echo file_get_contents('index.html');
}
?>
```

This is fine and it does the job. What I don't like though is the fact that for this simple timestamp check, the php interpreter must be run on each request. Don't get me wrong, it's not a serious performance issue, I just don't like the principle.

So, I was thinking getting some smart `.htaccess` scripting to do the timestamp check instead. My dream achievement is as follows:

**Check if index.html is older than one hour. If yes, call *index.php*. If not, serve *index.html*.**

Being new to Apache configs, I did some googling first and dived into `mod_expires`. That didn't do exactly what I wanted but it was a good start - I could set expiry relative to file's last day modified. But that doesn't do the index.html/index.php conditions, only fulfills the "if the file is old, serve a new one" scenario. I've also read about if/else for Apache > 2.4 but don't really see the way here to say "if a file is older than one hour, do stuff" using mod_expires.

I'm not looking for any workarounds or other types of caching/serving static files. I'm bugged with this very scenario just out of curiosity.

Any suggestions from your side appreciated (and thanks for your time).

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a Cron Job that runs every hour no matter if a visitor has hit your site or not.

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

```
0 * * * * wget -O - -q http://www.website.com/cron.php
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of cron jobs but as I said, I don't want any alternative solutions. I'm plain curious whether this can be achieved by a plain .htaccess config.